# SDWebImage change cacheMaxCacheAge

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

How I can change a static value `cacheMaxCacheAge` when I use SDWebImage? What way is good? I need to cache images for 5 minutes.

Comment: [SDWebImageManager sharedManager].imageCache.maxCacheAge = 300;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **SDWebImage 5.0+** maxCacheAge renamed to maxDiskAge. You can set maximum caching time in seconds like this.

**Objetive-c**

```
[SDImageCache sharedImageCache].config.maxDiskAge = 60 * 5; //5 minutes
```

**Swift 4+**

```
SDImageCache.shared.config.maxDiskAge = 60 * 5 //5 minutes
```

Reference link: https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/wiki/5.0-Migration-guide

Comment: should maxDiskSize be maxDiskAge in your Objective C example?

Comment: Thanks @FeichengMaike for pointing out, both are different, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

SDWebImage is providing `maxCacheAge` property to set the maximum caching time in seconds. We can use shared instance method to access this property.

```
[SDImageCache sharedImageCache].config.maxCacheAge = 60 * 5; //5 minutes
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5+ , SDWebImage 5.13 +**, **tvOS15+ and maybe other platforms**

I found out that simply setting new `maxDiskAge` property on tvOS 15+ is not enough when  storing image with  `SDImageCache.shared.store` , but you indeed need to manually delete the old cache with `deleteOldFiles()` function. It happens in my case, even though the performing of old cache deletion is allegedly done by library itself after terminating the app [as specified in following SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172659/14559220). This might be only the case for tvOS, but I am not entirely sure if the problem persists also on another platforms. Here is the solution that worked for me:

Deleting expired cache:

```
SDImageCache.shared.deleteOldFiles()
```

Setting max cache disk time in seconds:

```
SDImageCache.shared.config.maxDiskAge = 100000
```

Storing images to disk:

```
SDImageCache.shared.store(image, forKey: key, toDisk: true)
```